# Racket scribble not showing hyperlinks

Tags: scheme, racket, scribble

I have tried following code statements to show a URL:

```
#lang scribble/base

@title{Testing Hyperlinks}

@section{URLs}

Getting started: @hyperlink["https://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/getting-started.html"]

Getting started: @hyperlink{"https://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/getting-started.html"}

Getting started: @(hyperlink "https://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/getting-started.html")
```

The html page is generating without any error with command "$ scribble hyperlinks.scrbl" but it is not displaying the URLs with any of the hyperlink statement:

```
Testing Hyperlinks

1 URLs
Getting started:

Getting started:

Getting started:
```

The generated html file contains following link:

```
<p>Getting started:</p><p><a href="&quot;https://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/getting-started.html&quot;"></a></p>
```

Where is the problem and how can I correct this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`hyperlink`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/base.html#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fbase..rkt%29._hyperlink%29%29) function expects the actual textual content to be supplied separately from the link itself. That is, you’re supposed to use it like this:

```
@hyperlink["http://example.com"]{some link}
```

And the rendered HTML will look like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com">some link</a>
```

If you want to typeset a literal URL, which links to its own content, use the [`url`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/base.html#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fbase..rkt%29._url%29%29) function instead.

Comment: Yes, it works. Somehow the documentation is very technical and does not have simple examples.

Comment: Yes, the scribble documentation in particular is missing a lot of examples, and it's even weirder because they have to present each function is s-expression notation, but you would normally use them with at-expression notation